# How to pass a variable in a component to a function

Tags: react-native

I'm using a library to create a calculator and want to pass the value I compute to another function.

Library Here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calculator

There is an 'onAccept' prop with a data type: **(value : number , text : string ) => void**

I understand that this value / number is what I need to pass but I don't understand how to format my code to accommodate this. My code thus far is below where I am calling the acceptAdd function which will work with the passed value. I want to pass the calculator's value to acceptAdd. Thank you for any assistance.

Current Code:

```
onAccept = {acceptAdd}
```

Comment: Please share the complete code from where and to where you want to pass the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you haven't shared your detailed attempt, let's take assumptions from the lib you are using. Am assuming you are using a Functional Component, but this can be similar to a class component.

With TypeScript.

---

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { Calculator } from 'react-native-calculator';

// Lets Assume this is your calculator component
const App = (): JSX.Element => {
  // Create handler to handle your onAccept which mirror
  // the function signature from the docs.
  const acceptAdd = (value: number, text: string): void => {
    // Do whatever you want with the value.
    console.log({ value, text });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Calculator style={{ flex: 1 }} onAccept={acceptAdd} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Or in plain JavaScript

---

```js
const App = () => {
  const acceptAdd = (value, text) => {
    // Do whatever you want with the value.
    console.log({ value, text });
  };

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <Calculator style={{ flex: 1 }} onAccept={acceptAdd} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thanks so much the second format worked for me. Out of curiosity how does the library know to pass value and text into acceptAdd. Usually with object oriented languages you have to pass it like acceptAdd(value)

Comment: @Sachu, you are most welcome. As per your question, because that's the signature of the [expected prop function](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calculator#props),  as written by the author. They define `onAccept (value : number , text : string ) => void`. Telling you that that function accepts a value and text and returns nothing. In react, when you define a function prop for a component, you are telling it what to expect that when i'ts eventually called, a function with a matching signature.

Comment: You might wish to read about [function expressions](https://javascript.info/function-expressions), [declarations](https://javascript.info/function-expressions#function-expression-vs-function-declaration), [function invocation](https://yehudakatz.com/2011/08/11/understanding-javascript-function-invocation-and-this/) and [callback](https://javascript.info/callbacks).

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and resources it makes a lot more sense now